# How to target tag after a class?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="pre-class">
    <div>100%</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to remove the percent (%) on the text inside the div after the class `pre-class` with `textContent.replace("%","")` but I just can't target that specific div

(I'm working on a longer website with a lot of divs and I can't add an ID to it because it's from a shortcode.)

I thought I could do something like this:

```
var textContent = document.getElementsByClassName('gamipress-progress-bar-completed').getElementsByTagName('div');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically there. Don't forget that getElementsByClassname returns an array, so simply use `[0]` to retrieve the element. You'll see it working in the snippet below:

```js
var textContent = document.getElementsByClassName('pre-class')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML;

console.log(textContent)
```

```html
<div class="pre-class">
    <div>100%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let containers = document.getElementsByClassName("pre-class");
for (var i = 0; i<containers.length; i++) {
  let current = containers[i];
  let textNode = current.children[0];
  textNode.innerText = textNode.innerText.replace(/(\d)%/, '$1');
};
```

```html
<div class="pre-class">
    <div>100%</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use `element.querySelector()` (or `querySelectorAll`) to find the correct element(s) to replace.

```js
let textNode = document.querySelector(".pre-class > div"); // use querySelectorAll in case there can be multiple matches.
textNode.innerText = textNode.innerText.replace(/(\d)%/, '$1');
```

```html
<div class="pre-class">
    <div>100%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why iterating through children ?

Comment: In case there are more elements with the `pre-class` class applied to it; and retrieving the first node under it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector`

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div.pre-class > div');
div.innerText = div.innerText.replace('%', '')
```

```html
<div class="pre-class">
    <div>100%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the div will be the first direct child of the pre-class div, and you have one element with "pre-class" class, this will work

```js
const textContent = document.querySelector('.pre-class').firstElementChild.textContent;

console.log(textContent.replace('%', ''))
```

```html
<div class="pre-class">
    <div>100%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the child selector (>).

```
let textDiv=document.querySelector(".pre-class > div");
textDiv.textContent=textDiv.textContent.replace("%","");
```

This will replace the first direct div inside .pre-class. You can adjust the position of divs using pseudo classes. Like for example, if you want to select the second div inside .pre-class, you would use:

```
<div class="pre-class">
    <div>100%</div>
     <div>200%</div>
    <div>300%</div>
</div>

let textDiv=document.querySelector(".pre-class > div:nth-child(2)");
textDiv.textContent=textDiv.textContent.replace("%","");
```

Comment: thank you so much! this helped me alot! as well as others who mentioned querySelector

Answer (score 0):

```js
const content = document.querySelector('.pre-class > div').innerHTML;
content.replace("%", "");
```

```html
<div class="pre-class">
    <div>100%</div>
</div>
```

This is another way of selecting the div nested in your .pre-class div. Perhaps not the best way of doing this but it's handy to know querySelector works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of `divs` inside `div.pre-class` , its better to add specific data attribute to each child `div` and select the  desired `div` using this:

```js
< div class = 'pre-class' >
  <div data-order = 'first' > 1 < /div> 
  <div data-order = 'second' > 2 < /div> 
  <div data-order = 'third' > 3 < /div> 
</div>


///////////
document.querySelector('div[data-order="first"]')
```